# azcopy version 10.x does not work with source of Azure storage table and destination of Azure Storage Blob container

Tags: azure-blob-storage, azcopy

a) I executed
azcopy login
logged in with passcode on the browser
b) azcopy cp "https://mystorage1.table.core.windows.net/AppLog?accountKey"
"https://mystorage1.blob.core.windows.net/archive/appLogs?accountKey"

```
    INFO: Authenticating to destination using Azure AD
    INFO: Any empty folders will not be processed, because source and/or destination doesn't have full folder support
This is the error I get:
    failed to perform copy command due to error: cannot start job due to error: cannot scan the path \\?\C:\myFolder\azcopy\https:\mystorage1.table.core.windows.net\AppLog, please verify that it is a valid.
```

NOTE: In other tests I was able to do a blob storage container to other blob storage container, that worked fine.

Also with older version of 8.x I was able to copy with this command:

```
AzCopy /Source:"https://mystorage1.table.core.windows.net/AppLog" /Dest:"https://mystorage1.blob.core.windows.net/archive/appLogs" /SourceKey:"accountKey" /Destkey:"accountKey"
```

example response:

```
PS C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\AzCopy> .\Azcopy.exe /Source:"https://***********.table.core.windows.net/AppLog" /Dest:"https://**********.blob.core.windows.net/archive/appLo
gs" /SourceKey:"*********" /Destkey:"******"
[2021/09/14 06:28:56] Manifest file for this export operation is: "*********_AppLog_20210914T062856.7516140Z.manifest".
[2021/09/14 06:28:56] All table entities have been downloaded.
[2021/09/14 06:28:57] Validating the integrity of data file list...
[2021/09/14 06:28:57] Validation of data file list passed.
[2021/09/14 06:28:57]
Transfer summary:
-----------------
Total entities transferred: 21
Elapsed time:               00.00:00:01
```

If direct azure storage Table to storage blob container copy is not successful I may have to do 2 steps first export to a local (csv) file from my azure storage table and then upload local csv file to blob container. I was trying to avoid doing 2 step approach, if any of you have any ideas on direct copy (from storage table to storage blob container) please let me know. I have the solution in AzCopy 8.x but was wondering if I can use latest version.

Comment: Hello , Copy from / to table storage is not supported in recent versions of azcopy. please refer this [Github Issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-azcopy/issues/161) . As of Now azcopy is only used for Blob storage operations. You can use [ADF copy tool activity](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/copy-activity-overview) to copy from [table storage](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-azure-table-storage?tabs=data-factory) to [blob storage](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-azure-blob-storage?tabs=data-factory).

Comment: Thanks AnsumanBal-MT! I have implemented using AzCopy ver 8.x for now, I will wait to upgrade azcopy until this is available for use a different approach with latest version!

Comment: @SuryaGovi, my guess is you'll be waiting forever.

Answer (score 0):

As Suggested By @AnsumanBal-MT Copy from / to table storage is not supported in recent versions of azcopy.

If you want to copy data to and from your [Azure Table storage service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/tables/table-storage-overview) , then install AzCopy version 7.3.